# Not able to get sliders working with ggplot's geom_hist, but working with base R hist()

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have been working all day trying to introduce a slider input for my shiny dashboard with no luck. I am kind of a newbie to R, but can usually fumble my way through. I am able to get it working with the hist() function, but not geom_histogram. I would just use hist(), but I need to be able to graph multiple histograms on the same graph. I won't know how many I need in advance. It will be determined by one of my data columns how many are necessary. I have that working with geom_histogram, but it looks like that is not an easy task using hist()

I copied basic code word for word from bookdown.org to try code that should definitely work, and that does not work for me either. Is there some reason that reactivity might not be working for me with ggplot2? Is there something that I could be missing? I get the slider, but sliding it has no effect.

This basic code from bookdown.org that I tried that does not work for me is:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
 
  sliderInput(inputId = "number_of_bins", 
            label = "Choose wisely the number of bins",
            value = 10, min = 0, max = 100, step = 10), 
  
  plotOutput(outputId = "our_first_reactive_plot")
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
output$our_first_reactive_plot <- renderPlot({
  
  ggplot(mpg, aes(x = hwy)) +
    geom_histogram(bins = input$number_of_bins) # collecting and incorporating
  
})
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. Your code works fine for me.

Comment: I know! I just can't figure out why this won't work.